# jQuery selectors not working after ASP.NET postback (no UpdatePanels, not AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

I need to make a change to an old page as quickly as possible, and the effort to AJAX-ify it in order to obviate postbacks would take too long (making a more correct version of it will have to come later, this new functionality needs to be in place ASAP). The javscript changes required are too complicated to attempt entirely in the plain JS the page currently uses for everything (it's enough of a mess as is), so I decided to implement the new functionality quickly using jQuery.

Everything works fine until there's a postback, after which the document ready function still runs, but the selectors no longer find anything. I'm not using ASP.NET AJAX, so there's no UpdatePanels or partial postbacks.

What's happening and how can I fix it in the simplest, fastest possible way?

Answer (score 1):

While `$(document).ready()` is ideal for one-time initialization routines, it leaves you hanging if you have code that needs to be re-run after every partial postback. Of course there are ways to get around this. But can you try using .NET franeworks `pageLoad()` and bind your events there and see if selectors still work after postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad() {
    $("#Button1").on('click', function () {
       ...
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not doing a partial postback because there's no AJAX invovled here at all

Answer (score 0):

If you have a a trigger attached to the DOM, and that element in the DOM gets replaced, the trigger will be lost.  Such a trigger might look like `$('#mydiv').on('click', function(){});`.

Instead, you have the attach the trigger to a DOM element that wont be replaced. The easy way is to attach this to the `document`, but you'd be recommended to narrow the search.

Such a selector would look like

```
$('document').on('click', '#mydiv', function() {});
```

This means that if the element #mydiv gets recreated, then the trigger is not lost.

You can read more about delegated events at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I need to actually manipulate DOM objects on the page during load, not just wire up events. Document.ready() is running again on the postback, there's just no content inside of the document object on the second run for some reason.

Comment: How are you determining there is no content in the DOM on the second run? Is the response return zero content, or are events on that content just not firing when you expect them to?

Comment: It might help to post some sample code. Perhaps the JS for your jQuery post, or a snippet of code trying to do the DOM manipulation, and a snapshot of relevant parts of the DOM before and after the post. There's jsfiddle.net to save HTML, CSS and JS. You could do two of those, one before and one after, with the different HTML content (or one that hardcodes the response of the AJAX as a click event, rather than an actual POST).